# Reserving multiple jobs from a beanstalkd queue

Tags: ruby, beanstalkd

Is there a way I can reserve multiple jobs from a beanstalkd queue at once?

I'm making requests to an external API that can return up to 10 results per query. They limit the number of requests I can make each day, so the more results I get per request the better.

I couldn't find any mention of this functionality in the documentation so I'm using this workaround. Does anyone know of a better way to achieve this? Or a more appropriate tool for the job than beanstalkd perhaps?

```
loop do
  sleep(0.3)

  while @beanstalk.tubes[example].peek(:ready)
    jobs = []

    catch(:done) do
      10.times do |i|
        if @beanstalk.tubes[example].peek(:ready) then
          job = @beanstalk.tubes[example].reserve(0)
          jobs << job.body
          job.delete
        else
          throw(:done)
        end
      end
    end

    process(jobs)

  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reserve several jobs concurrently by calling `reserve`
several times in a row before deleting or releasing those jobs.

Based on the code sample you provided, it could look something
roughly like this:

```
loop do
  timeout = nil
  jobs = []

  begin
    10.times do |i|
      jobs << @beanstalk.tubes[example].reserve(timeout)
      timeout = 0
    end
  rescue Beaneater::TimedOutError
    # nothing to do
  end

  process(jobs.map{|j| j.body})

  jobs.map do |job|
    job.delete
  end
end
```

Comment: I've done similar in PHP before now. Stored the results of `reserve()` in an array, process them all en-mass, and then delete the jobs (or maybe just those that succeeded). KR is the truest expert on beanstalkd, of course.

Comment: Hey, I just edited this answer to remove the busy-wait loop and replace it with an indefinite timeout on the first job. Sorry I missed that the first time around. This version will process jobs more promptly and avoid wasting worker CPU.